# How do I display drop shadows for line charts with Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make a drop shadow for some data I have. [View the current image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GERh0.png)

I can't increase the drop shadow's width. Is there a way to do it?

Here's what I currently have:

```
plt.plot(times, past_values,color='red',path_effects=[path_effects.SimpleLineShadow(shadow_color="red"),path_effects.Normal()])
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the `linewidth` argument to `SimpleLineShadow`.

```
plt.plot(times, past_values,color='red',path_effects=[path_effects.SimpleLineShadow(shadow_color="red", linewidth=5),path_effects.Normal()])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simple add `shadow=True`
Here is an example

```
plt.plot(times, past_values,color='red',shadow=True)
```

Try it it may work

Comment: `plt.plot`  has no property 'shadow'

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patheffects import PathPatchEffect, SimpleLineShadow, Normal
sns.set()

plt.plot([1,2,3],[1,4,9],color='red',path_effects=[SimpleLineShadow(shadow_color="red", linewidth=10),Normal()])
```